# Best structure for MySQL table to hold statistical data

Tags: mysql, performance, web-applications, statistics, scalability

I have a need for a solution that would allow me to track every single click (and the link clicked, and the date) in a web application (PHP5 / MySQL5.7). The simplest solution is obviously a simple table :

```
CREATE TABLE stats_data (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    log_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    link VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm not such how this scales up performance-wise, as the expected amount of clicks **per day** could well **go above 10000**.

1. **Is this a reliable solution, say, after 5 months of data stored ?**
2. **What optimizations could make this solution perform better**?
3. **If not, what would be a better solution approach for this ?**

Comment: changing `link VARCHAR(512) ` to `link_id INT` is one obvious optimisation.

Comment: It really depends on the queries you will be using.  Please describe them, or show us tentative `SELECT` statements.  (1.5M records after 5 months is not a lot.)

Comment: Problem was solved, as show by the accepted answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it depends on your use-case. What queries do you want to run over this dataset?

I would definitely recommend some document oriented database (like Redis or MongoDb), but as I said, it depends how will you use your data.

If you want to stick to MySQL, I have some advice on how to make that solution more reliable.

1. Dont save every click into database each time is clicked, but store it into cache (memcached for example) and once every hour save into MySQL
2. Make own table for each month to not make searches in one large table. And backup that table each month.

Comment: The use case is, well, pulling statistical data out of it. In my web application I'm looking to let the user see (for example) the number of clicks in a specific month, day, or custom period. Queries (other than insertion) would be most of the time getting rows within a specific date range.

1. Looking into it, thank.
2. I like that idea, thanks again.

Comment: What about saving data into some raw tables and use some daily routine (cron) to aggregate valuable data into some light-weight tables (like one table for number of click per day, other for number of unique visitors. Then you would not be burdened by your raw table size, cause you would only save your clicks, then aggregate at midnight and in the best case scenario, delete aggregated rows. You can save them into other db (for example) to backup them for later use (if some new use-case arises).

Comment: Maybe another important factor is how much time do you want to invest into solution :) because abstraction an aggregation optimizations can be infinite :D

Comment: Yes, I have already looked into having some sort of cron job do that but the problem is as follows. By aggregation I guess you mean summing the number of click, say per day, and putting it into a new table. The idea is that we want to keep track of the links clicked too, which are probably unique link per entry. That would either mean we get rid of the link and just store the click count, or we'd end up just duplicating the table into another one. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, time is also a factor. That's why your 2nd solution seems like a viable solution to me, giving a table could easily hold a few million entries, monthly tables seems ok to me. Implementing those and seting your reply as chosen answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: About that aggregations, it always depends on use-cases. There is no best solutions, just spreading query computation into time. Its strategy I often use in larger projects - one table for storing raw and full data and some nightly routine which fills the other table for reading. I never want to discard collected data, because it often happens that you need it sometime in the future. But its meaningless to search in such large table. So I do a sequence of transformations, which in my most complex experience ended in destroying one big table into about 20 lighter ones - business intelligence

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could possible put the links in a separate table and have your table reference that as a foreign key. Should possible make it faster to for example check the number of clicks on a specific link.

Depending on how accurate you want the data you could also aggregate it into another table in maby a nightly running operation of some sort (scheduled sp should work).
That way you can have a table where you for example can se how many times a link was clicked in a specific interval, a day or an hour or whatever suits your needs. I've used this approach at work where we store statistic data on web-service calls in an application with very heavy load and it has been working fine with no performance issues what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of thinks you can do to ensure performance:

- **Index** `log_date` column **so queries can run faster** when searching for results by dates range (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html)
- **Create partitions** by `log_date` column (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-types.html)

By partitioning data by date columns you can "separate" data by hour / day / week / month / year... whatever you want...

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(35),
joined DATE NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(joined) ) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1960),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1970),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1980),
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1990),
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

Therefore, imagining that you separates data by week, when you search by a log with date equal to '2016-08-25', that record will be searched only on logs with dates between '2016-08-22' and '2016-08-28'.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you ! This is probably what I'm looking for. An answer above suggested creating tables by month. Easy to do that. But partitioning looks way more elegant, assuming it achieves the same goal ? in other words, would a 'partition' be able to hold a couple million rows (that is a month's worth f data), I assume ?

Thank you for the indexing tip, BTW. I also moved the links to another table and made the link_id columns a foreign key to that.